# count occurrences across multiple csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to count the occurrences of unique email adresses. In each csv file, multiple people can have the same last or first name. Only the emails are unique. There are only three columns (excel: A,B,C).

file1.csv

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|          A          |         B        |      C        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Last Name      |     First Name   |    Mail       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Johnson       |       Emma       |   e.j@abc.com |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Johnson       |       Max        |   m.j@abc.com |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|        ...          |         ...      |     ...       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

file2.csv

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Last Name      |     First Name   |    Mail       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Smith         |       Linda      |    l.s@abc.com|
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Johnson       |       Max        |    m.j@abc.com|
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|        ...          |         ...      |     ...       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

...

file89.csv

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Last Name      |     First Name   |    Mail       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Miller        |       Jeremy     |   je.m@abc.com|
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Johnson       |       Max        |    m.j@abc.com| 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|        ...          |         ...      |     ...       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

The program should create an output csv file (can be a .txt file too), that counts the occurences (>2) of the unique mail adress and outputs the first and last name.
output.csv

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|---------------|
|      Last Name      |     First Name   |     Mail      |   Occurrence  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|---------------|
|       Johnson       |       Max        |    m.j@abc.com|       3       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|---------------|
|        ...          |         ...      |     ...       |      ...      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|---------------|
```

possible algorithm:

```
create new temprary csv file : temp.csv
for (i = 1; i <= 89; i++)
    append content of file[i] into temp.csv
//now we have one csv file, instead of 89

count occurence of unique email in temp.csv
if occurence > 2
    save column[0], column[1], column[2] and occurence
    into output.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first load all your CSV's in `pandas` DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_files = ["file1.csv", ..., "file89.csv"]

dataframes = [pd.read_csv(fi) for fi in list_of_files]
```

Then, we can collapse all the DataFrames into a single big DataFrame:

```
big_df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Then, assuming the combination of name+surname+email are consistent, we can do the following:

```
with_occ = big_df.groupby(big_df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'occurrences'})

print(with_occ)
#   name  surname         email  occurrences
# 0  Kat        L       s@m.com           1
# 1  Max  Johnson  max@mail.com           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't load the CSV files all at once!
That being said, I read each CSV file and created a dictionary for the email addresses. Later on, you can easily select email addresses that have occurred more than one time.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


d = {}
for f in tqdm(os.listdir(CSV_FILES_DIR)):
    tmp_df = pd.read_csv(f"{CSV_FILES_DIR}/{f}", index_col=0)
    for e in tmp_df["email"]:
        if e not in d:
            d[e] = 0
        else:
            d[e] += 1
```